# Problems With Regular Expressions and Lists in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, list

I created a list from a subtitle file (.srt) in which every line is inside a index of the list. Now I want to erase some lines, specially lines starting with the time interval in the format "xx:xx:xx,xxx --> xx:xx:xx,xxx". I did some research (ok, quite superficial research on a complex topic, I might add) and tried to create the following sub:

```
Private Shared Sub listCleaning(ByRef sList As List(Of String))
    For Each line As String In sList
        Dim pattern As String = "\b\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d --> \b\d\d:\d\d:\d\d:\d\d,\d\d\d"
        Dim reg As New Regex(pattern)

        If line = "" Or Integer.TryParse(line, Nothing) Or reg.IsMatch(pattern) Then
            sList.Remove(line)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now Im having two problems:

1. My Regular Expression is not beeing correctly parsed.
2. When I have a valid condition on my If Block and the line gets removed, I have a InvalidOperationException when hiting next since the list has changed.

Can anyone help me to write a correct RegEx and a way to iterate through the list removing the unwanted lines?

tnx in advance.

EDIT:

Ok, Tim got most of the problem out but I still need a RegEx that suits the pattern "xx:xx:xx,xxx --> xx:xx:xx,xxx". Anyone willing to care?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `^` at the start of the regex to anchor the search to the start of the string.

Comment: Also, you can't remove items from a list you are iterating over using `For Each`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are my changes to your original code.

First, I don't use the for each loop, but the more traditional for loop
Second, Loop in reverse, so your delete goes to the end of the list
Third, the regex pattern should be outside the loop

```
Private Shared Sub listCleaning(ByRef sList As List(Of String)) 
    Dim pattern As String = "\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s+-->\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}" 
    Dim reg As New Regex(pattern) 
    Dim x as Integer
    For x = sList.Count - 1 to 0 step -1
        Dim line as string = sList(x)
                Console.WriteLine(line)
        If line = "" Or Integer.TryParse(line, Nothing) Or reg.IsMatch(line) Then 
               sList.Remove(line) 
        End If 
    Next 
End Sub
```

This is my test data:

```
Sub Main
    Dim sList as List(Of String) = new List(Of string)
    sList.Add("01:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("sdsdfsdfsd03 --> 02:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("03:01:01,003 --> 03:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("04:01:01,003 --> 04:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("05:01:01,003 --> 05:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("06:01:01,003 --> 06:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("07:01:01,003 --> 07:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("08:01:01,003 --> 08:02:02,003")
    sList.Add("09:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02 003")    

    console.WriteLine("Call listCleaning with " + sList.Count.ToString +  " elements")

    listCleaning(sList)

    console.WriteLine("Returned with " + sList.Count.ToString +  " elements")
    for each line as String in sList
        Console.WriteLine(line)
    next
End Sub
```

To get this output

```
Call listCleaning with 9 elements
09:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02 003
08:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02,003
07:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02,003
06:AA:01,003   --> 02:02:02,003
05:01:01,003 -->    02:02:02,003
04:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02,003
03:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02,003
sdsdfsdfsd03 --> 02:02:02,003
01:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02,003
Returned with 3 elements
sdsdfsdfsd03 --> 02:02:02,003
06:AA:01,003   --> 02:02:02,003
09:01:01,003 --> 02:02:02 003
```

Comment: Well, odly enough, running Steve's code every iteration my "line" variable gets assigned "" and gets removed on the if block and sList.Count is decreased by one but I can't see any change whatsoever in the list. Everything is the same but the count index...

Comment: Strange, with my test data it works as expected. Could you show some of your data lines?

Comment: There is a sample of my data: http://pastebin.com/u3fycnPS I have an array with the correct time intervals that I want to replace in that list. First I have to count in which line (each index of my list is a line) are the wrong intervals and replace them by the ones already in my array.

Comment: Again, also using your data, the code above clears the list from the lines with timing info. Don't know what to say now. Please recheck your code (Also the regex pattern works).

Comment: Yes, I was wrong Steve... yesterday I was already so drained that I was not debugging right. Now the code seems just perfect, thank you very much. If I had some reputation I would rate your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Answer to point 2:

You cannot modify a collection during iteration. So you

1. need to store the items you want to remove in another collection or
2. iterate in reverse (thanks @Oded) or
3. use [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) (look at the bottom) or
4. use Linq:

   ```
   var dontRemove = From line In sList
       Where line <> "" AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(line, Nothing) AndAlso Not reg.IsMatch(pattern)
   ```

Now you can safely remove these lines from the list or just create a new List:

```
sList = dontRemove.ToList()
```

If you're using a `List(Of T)` the best option is to use [`List.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) and pass the predicate which items should be removed:

```
Dim regex = New Regex("\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\s+-->\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}", RegexOptions.Compiled)
sList.RemoveAll(Function(line) line.Length = 0 _
                    OrElse Integer.TryParse(line, Nothing) _
                    OrElse Not regex.IsMatch(line))
```

---

> what's the best way to iterate in reverse for a List

```
For index As Int32 = sLines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Dim line = sLines(index)
Next`
```

Comment: tnx for the fast reply guys. But what's the best way to iterate in reverse for a List? Knowing that I don't know at compile time the size of my list....

Comment: @Virtus: Edited my answer again to show. But i would prefer one of the other three options. The best is `List.RemoveAll`.

Comment: Tim, it works great, thanks. But i didnt get that argument that you passed to the .RemoveAll(), the Function(l) l = "" part, can you shed some light on this please? Also, it's not getting the right syntax to make the RegEx work...

Comment: @Virtus: a [Predicate(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx#Y630) delegate is like a method that returns `true` or `false`. So you can pass anything that returns a boolean, for example `Integer.TryParse` or a custom method.

Comment: Hey Tim, tnx for your help. Indeed using the .removeAll seems interesting, but It's not "seeing" the RegEx condition... the RegEx is correct, and works fine on Steve's code. Any ideas?

Comment: You should show what you've tried. I've edited my answer (starting with `Dim pattern ...`. But i've reversed the logic(`Not Regex.IsMatch`) since i assume that you want to remove what does not match the pattern and it works with Steve's sample data and Regex(+1), 7 items remain in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Tim. It works nicely now. I confess I'm pretty weak in delegates and RegEx and you and Steve showed me some good code here. I'll work on that on my studies.Tnx!